# In Facebook PHP Sdk, how can I add a footer link just below Like and Comment?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I've seen this thing in a lot of applications.
http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/2284/99528077.png

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is not to late [but I just had the same problem], you need to use actions key. Here is an example from facebook graph api:
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Check out this funny article' \
     -F 'link=http://www.example.com/article.html' \
     -F 'picture=http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg' \
     -F 'name=Article Title' \
     -F 'caption=Caption for the link' \
     -F 'description=Longer description of the link' \
     **-F 'actions={"name": "View on Zombo", "link": "http://www.zombo.com"}' \**
     -F 'privacy={"value": "ALL_FRIENDS"}' \
     -F 'targeting= {"countries":"US","regions":"6,53","locales":"6"}' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed

Cheers...